# Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload-gambar

Tags: file-upload, laravel-6

I want to upload an image using Laravel storage file system in my admin data. However, there's an error when I attempt to upload an image. please help me. Call to a member function getClientOriginalName()

this is my UploadController

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UploadController extends Controller
{

 public function form()
{
    return view('form-upload');
}

public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('image');

  // Mendapatkan Nama File

  $nama_file = $file->getClientOriginalName();

  $uniqueFileName = uniqid() . $file->getClientOriginalName() . '.' . $file- 
  >getClientOriginalExtension();
  // Mendapatkan Extension File
  $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

  // Mendapatkan Ukuran File
  $ukuran_file = $file->getSize();

  // Proses Upload File
  $destinationPath = 'uploads';
  $file->move($destinationPath,$file->getClientOriginalName());

 }

 }
```

and this is my upload-form.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Tutorial Upload File Laravel - Belajarphp.net</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Script Upload File</h3>
<form action="upload-gambar" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<input type="file" name="gambar">
<Br>    
<button type="submit">Upload File</button> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your error is pretty clear; you are calling `getClientOriginalName()` on null;

Your stack trace will even tell you what line of what file it occurs on.

In this case, it is easy to figure out:

```
$file = $request->file('image');
```

Will get a file from the request called `image`.

Look at your form field for the file:

```
<input type="file" name="gambar">
```

The input name is `gambar`; this is what it comes through in the request as.

So at this point `$file` is `null` because there is no property in the request called `image`.

To solve the issue, you need to:

```
$file = $request->file('gambar');
```